# Create function to get value from listboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Access 2010, Windows 7
Have a form that has several list boxes with dropdowns. Trying to create a function that will return the value in a row selected in a list box. Here is the code I have;

```vb
 Public Function listboxSel(listName As Control) As Integer
  Dim rowIndex As Integer
  Dim rowValue As String
  Dim rowIsSelected As Integer
  Dim result As String

  ' ListBox row index clicked
  rowIndex = Me.xxxxx.ListIndex

  ' Row value clicked
  rowValue = Me.xxxxx.Column(0)
  rowIsSelected = Me.xxxxx.Selected(rowIndex)
  listboxSel = rowValue
  End Function
```

First, I don't know how to pass the name of a listbox to the function.
Second, I don't think `listName As Control` is correct.  I've been trying bits of code I found on the web to no avail.

Comment: Multi Select is set to None

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the selected item for a listbox, you can use this code here. I have an event called invoiceButton_Click which triggers the code to find the selected item in the list box and do something with it. I have taken out my code but left what's necessary.

```
'Moves selected item from items listbox to invoice listbox
Private Sub invoiceButton_Click()

Dim rowIndex As Integer, pos1 As Integer, i As Integer, rowValue As String, str As String, strSQL As String
Dim strToCut As String, tempStr As String, JobLinkCode As String, val As String

' ListBox row index clicked
rowIndex = Me.lbItems.ListIndex

'Checks if an item in the listbox is selected. If nothing is selected, end the program. If something is selected, Do Something.
'The .Column(0) is telling my code to use the first column of the listbox since they can contain multiple values.
If IsNull(Me.lbItems.Column(0)) Then
    End
Else

    'Do Something

End If

End Sub
```

Also, you don't have to pass a listbox into a function/sub. You can access that control anywhere on that form, therefore it is not necessary to pass it in as a parameter. Just use Me.[listbox name].[function you want to use] to access it.

Hope this helps!